# Is it possible to create wordpress category pages like home pages? (designed)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I see in most WP templates that the homepage is very beautiful, designed with banners etc. Is it possible to do the same for each category page (after all these pages are landing pages)?

I want it to show both promotional stuff on top (banners etc.) and latest category posts on bottom. The default is only latest posts.

Thanks

Comment: We dont know what theme you are currently using. Some Wordpress themes have the banners at the top for specific page templates, maybe try searching for a theme with that ability and use that theme instead.

Comment: Well, as you asked if it is possible: yes it is possible. We ( stackoverflowers) can't magically know how to apply help for you here without code/examples/actual solvable problems/questions for us

Comment: See my answer @user1436942 & vote UP please or accept it. It was best i could write for such question. :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your question is not clear and you just asked a general question for that answer is **Yes absolutely Possible**. Without any specific information of theme or error, we cant help you.

Here is some thought:

You can easily customize wordpress theme category page `category.php` or even if you want a different category template for only one category, you can do that. To do that, create `category-[slug].php` or `category-[id].php` file in your theme files - replace `slug` or `id` whatever you use with that of category you want a different tempelate.

Once you edit template for category page, you can add all options yourself - Good option is to display a Slider of category page and query posts for that category only to show on that slider or show promotional stuff on top from that category in slider or show banners whatever you want.

For example, you can alter your query to display latest posts from that category only to show in slider etc like using following query:

```
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => 5,
'offset'          => 0,
'category_name'   => $current_category,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'post_status'     => 'publish' );

$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

If it's using WP_Query, your query should look something like this:

```
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
$cat_posts = new WP_Query('showposts=5&category_name='.$current_category);

while ($cat_posts->have_posts())

...
```

And of course you can put a flag for **promoted** offer posts in your database as well and then add parameter of `'promoted' => 'true'` in above example queries to show only promoted posts in that slider etc.

p.s I just gave general thought - you need some knowledge of php, wordpress API for this and this is easily possible.

Vote up for me and accept the answer if i helped you.

There are many themes available in market with such options as well that you can use.